# Multi-bedroom or separate bedroom/living room areas at Orlando theme parks?

Tags: hotels, orlando, florida, disney, universal-studios

I'm trying to find somewhere to stay in either Disney World or Universal Studios (Orlando) with either multiple bedrooms or a separate bedroom and living area with a sofa bed or similar in the living area.  I've found Disney's "Deluxe Villas".  Are there any other options at either of these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Disney has a [page](http://disneyworld.disney.go.com/planning-guides/in-depth-advice/groups/) listing rooms suitable for larger groups.

All of these have a suite layout with one or more bedrooms separate from a lounge area that generally includes a sofa bed in some form.

Answer (score 2):

I've stayed at 3 of the WDW deluxe villa resorts and used both the 1 and 2 bedroom units...  they are very nice and come with great amenities.

Out of Wilderness Lodge, Animal Kingdom Lodge, and Beach Club Villas,  BCV is my favorite if only for the awesome pool and location (walk into Epcot).

For other recommendations, I'd check out the Marriott Vacation Club

Scroll down to the Orlando section http://www.marriottvacationclub.com/vacation-resorts/marriott-vacation-club-collection.shtml

We stay at the MVC when we're in Williamsburg and the 2-bdrm suites are enormous. Never tried the ones in Orlando, but they seem to have good ratings on tripadvisor.

Comment: MVC is basically time-shares that you can also rent as a hotel (just like the Disney Deluxe Villas)